# How do I check if numbers are repeating in pascal?

Tags: numbers, pascal

I want to make a program which I will check if here are any Armstron numbers (numbers which are equal to the cubes of it's figures, for example 153).

Which are also perfect numbers (numbers equal to the sum of it's divisors, not including itself, for example 28 (1+2+4+7+14))
below 1000. So I made a program to see if a number is Armstrong number and to see if it's perfect number.

```
program Armstrong;

var i,n,j,d,s,p:integer;

begin

  for i:=1 to 1000 do
  begin
   j:=i mod 10;
   d:=i div 10 mod 10;
   s:=i div 100;
   n:=j*j*j+d*d*d+s*s*s;

   if n=i then
    writeln(i);
  end;
end.
```

And for perfect numbers it's

```
program Perfect;

var n,s,i:integer;

begin
  for n:=1 to 1000 do
  begin
   s:=0;

   for i:=1 to n do
   begin
    if n mod i = 0 then
     s:=s+i;
   end;

   if s=n then
    writeln(n);
  end;
end.
```

So I don't know how to merge them and see if any number I get from the first program appears in the second as well.

Comment: I don't understand exactly your question, you can do a `boolean function` for Perfect and one for Armstrong and validate both. Another way is saving all the first in `array` and the same for the second and then make a `intersection`.

Answer (score 0):

I did Pascal long time back. So assume I have used `pseudo code` for this answer.

Remove your loop from Armstrong and put the code in this function.

```
function Armstrong(i: integer): integer;
   (* code goes here. And return 0 or 1 based on Armstrong *)
```

Remove your loop from Perfect, and put this code in this function

```
function Perfect(i: integer): integer;
   (* code goes here. And return 0 or 1 based on Perfect *)
```

Then call it from a loop like this way:

```
for i:=1 to 1000 do
  x = Armstrong(i);
  y = Perfect(i);
  if(x == 1 and y == 1) then
    (* do something *)
end;
```

Comment: thanks for this, but is there any way to for example save every number i get from armstrong to an array and every number from perfect numbers to another and check if there are any numbers repeating? i would like it this way because i can use it in more problems then

Comment: if x==1 then save the i into armstrong array. if y==1 then save i into perfect array. @Vkt0rS. I don't know much about Pascal these days so used integer, but boolean is easy to understand rather than 0/1.